# How to interpret limit notation

Tags: calculus, limits, definition

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)= L$ is by most; intuitively thought of "as $x$ gets close to $a$, $f(x)$ gets close to $L$", however my lecturer said this is not correct. She told me to go away and somehow find out why, by formal definition, the intuition "$f(x)$ is close to $L$, for all $x$ sufficiently close to $a$" is correct, not the former.

I went on to find examples; Simply consider; $f(x) = x/|x|$ when $x$ tends to some number.
and to recall an emphasise; “As $x$ gets close to $a$, $f(x)$ **gets** close to $L$”

The emphasise on gets is important as it suggests some change towards $L$, however when investigating, as $x$ tends to some number (like $0$), $f(x) = L$, no matter where on the domain you fly. There ceases to be a case in this function where $f(x)$ moves/gets close to $L$ anywhere.

“$f(x)$ is close to $L$, for all $x$ sufficiently close to $a$” includes the idea of ‘there exists some interval’ where $f(x)$ is close to $L$.

Is that a sufficient answer to the question? I can't find anything online.

Comment: Just to share more context, if needed, I was asked for a counter-example for the former intuition that (obviously) satisfies the second.

Comment: Do you have access to Stewart's Calculus, the Early Transcendentals version? I very much like how they explain all of this.

Comment: not correct in what sense? the epsilon, delta definition is clear, human languages are not. instead of wasting time with inaccuracies of human language why not just use epsilon delta definition?

Comment: I do actually, I have the 7th, at home, will study. Arjang; clarifying intuition is something aside from reading a definition. Newly aspiring Mathematicians need intuitive guidance when interpreting formal definitions for the first time, or something as above can occur frequently.

Comment: Maybe "gets close" is being considered not to apply if the function is locally constant or oscillates infinitely often near the point? This seems too sensitive to word interpretations that even other native speakers might not share.

Comment: In everyday speech, being near to $ L$ usually includes the assumption that you are not exactly at $L$.  In this context, however, being near to L  must include the possibility of being at $L,$ for example if $f(x)=L$ for every  $x$.

Comment: @FloSuess : that has nothing to do with intuition, it is suppose to be the exactly the opposite of intuition, to show that what seems intuitively correct is actually incorrect. How does one state "as x gets close to a, f(x) gets close to L" mathematically? it is vague human language, the epsilon delta definition is clear, the epsilon delta definition is there to avoid mistakes that are made due to intuition understanding.

Comment: I'm not promoting intuitive understanding is key to strong Mathematics, I've stated that for people like me, semantically explaining a definition in further simpler terms (human language) is key for people like me to start understanding concepts of Mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wise to tread carefully when semantically wording some intuition of a precise definition.

However; in this particular case there exists at least one function that smashes the first and is consistent with the latter. That is taking the limit as $x$ tends to $0$ of;

$f(x) = xsin(1/x)$.

The statement "as x gets close to a, f(x) gets close to L" simply does not hold because no matter how close to $a$ you get, your function continues to oscillate towards and away from L. However by definition the limit does exist.

Comment: "your function continues to oscillate towards and away from L.", so what if it oscillates with lesser and lesser amounts, that is exactly the reason why the limit exists. I think you have something else in your mind while asking the question. There is nothing contradicting "as x gets close to a, f(x) gets close to L".

Comment: I believe you're either mis-interpreting the question or just don't understand.

Comment: f(x) = xsin(1/x) does not provide a value 'a' in any case that is close to 0 such that f(x) gets close to L, because at some point of moving closer to 0 from 'a',  'a' will move away from L. That precisely shows that this "as x gets close to a, f(x) gets close to L", is an incorrect statement to represent the definition of a limit.

Comment: What do you thing gets closer means? it means that the distances gets less. |\$x\sin(x)x$ -L| gets smaller and smaller, that is why the limit exsists. I think you have mistaken "monotonically get closer to" with "gets closer to". Do you know the term monotonically decreasing? if you'd said it doesnt need get monotonically closer to limit then you be right, but you are saying it doesnt need to get closer to limit! then there is no limit in classical sense.

Comment: Your second sentence applies to the idea of some interval where the distance gets smaller, here we are speaking of of "as x gets close to a, f(x) gets close to L", there is no inclusion of a interval themed intuition. |\$\xsin(1/x)$ - L| does not get smaller as per x as x tends to L, of course this decreases as the interval is reduced to 0 we know this by the precise definition. But we are not talking about the definition we are showing this intuition is incorrect.

Comment: I need to take a week off to understand what you are saying :) You know what you are talking about..

Comment: It's good to never shy away from a argument though, and a strong remark should evolve around the fact that you mentioned; it is never wise to mix semantic intuition and precise mathematical definition, that's why I included it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [epsilon-delta definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) is pretty straight-forward:

$$\lim _{{x\to c}}f(x)=L\iff (\forall \varepsilon >0)(\exists \ \delta >0)(\forall x\in D)(0<|x-c|<\delta \ \Rightarrow \ |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon )$$

---

What does this mean?  Well, we break it down, part by part:

1. $(\forall\varepsilon>0)\dots(\dots|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon)$

This means that $f(x)$ can get arbitrarily close to $L$.

2. $(\exists \ \delta >0)(\forall x\in D)(0<|x-c|<\delta\dots)$

This means that the previous statement is true for every $x$ in the domain that is a certain distance from $c$, the value $x$ is approaching.

---

This is different from your definition in that it requires $f(x)$ to be close to $L$ with some maximum error $\varepsilon$ for **all** values $x$ close to $c$.  $x$ does not merely approach $c$, but instead, we must have

$$|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$

**for every $x$ close to $c$**.  The next requirement would then be that the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$ can keep getting smaller and smaller, and that it would still hold for every $x$ values a certain distance from $c$.

There is no such "$x$ approaches $c$" here.

---

So yes, $f(x)$ is close to $L$ for all $x$ sufficiently close to $a$ is the accurate statement.

---

In the example $x/|x|$, notice that no matter what $x$ value you choose, either the result will be $1$ or $-1$.  Let's imagine taking the limit to $10$.

$$\lim_{x\to10}\frac x{|x|}\stackrel?=1$$

We then make a table of values:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}x&f(x)\\\hline9&1\\9.9&1\\9.99&1\\\vdots&\vdots\\10.01&1\\10.1&1\\11&1\end{array}$$

Notice that $f(x)$ does not approach anything.  It is simply constant.  I suppose you could then try to fix your statement with "as $x$ approaches $10$, $f(x)$ is close to $1$ within some amount of error that tends to zero."

But that misses the intuition you can get with the epsilon-delta definition:

Notice that $f(x)-L=0\forall x>0$.  It thus follows that $|f(x)-L|=0<\varepsilon$, which holds when $\delta=10$.  $\delta$ needn't get smaller.  It simply needs to be small enough.

Comment: The first equation which you have written is in no way straightforward. And it is so much more difficult to understand what is really meant by it unless one is already good at real-analysis. To paraphrase differently writing mathematical statements using just mathematical symbols is more like writing legal documents which only a lawyer can understand. It is very important that the ideas of mathematics are communicated in language of communication (say English).

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is easier to understand the negation.

$f (x) $  could never be closer to $L $ $(|f (x)-L|>\epsilon) $

even if $x $ is closer to $a  \;(|x-a|<\delta) $

Comment: Is that constructive criticism on my answer given?

Comment: negated definitions are always worse than their constructive definition.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima : naah! no way I'll ever be a teacher, I am just math technician! :) Had bad teachers who used negations for definitions :(

Comment: @Arjang so happy to be different.